# Swapping right shift and delete key using xmodmap

Tags: keyboard, xmodmap

I'm unsure how to swap these 2, this is the thought process I had but am unsure how to get it working:

```
remove sh = Shift_R
remove dl = Delete

keysym Delete = Shift_R
keysym Shift_R = Delete

add sh = Delete
add dl = Shift_R
```

This is based on the code I use to swap caps lock and control.

Any thoughts?

xmodmap output:

```
dan@lantea:~$ xmodmap -pke | grep Shift_R
keycode  91 = Shift_R NoSymbol Shift_R
keycode 119 = Shift_R NoSymbol Shift_R
dan@lantea:~$ xmodmap -pke | grep Delete
keycode  62 = Delete NoSymbol Delete
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following commands:

```bsh
xmodmap -e "keycode 62 = Delete NoSymbol Delete"    #this will make Shift_R key to act as delete
xmodmap -e "keycode 119 = Shift_R NoSymbol Shift_R" #this will make Delete key to act as right shift
```

To get this change for every session, after you have run the ​​previous commands, create a file called `.xmodmap` with the new keymaps, using the following command:

```
xmodmap -pke > .xmodmap
```

Then, create a file called `.xinitrc` in your home directory, containing the following line/command:

```
xmodmap .xmodmap
```

And finally, make `.xinitrc` file to be executable:

```
chmod 755 ~/.xinitrc
```

Comment: I'm afraid the second xmodmap command, does not the delete key act as right shift. The first one works however.

Comment: @DanLaManna Don't be afraid, just try it. It should work. See the output of `xmodmap -pke | grep Shift_R` and `xmodmap -pke | grep Delete` commands.

Comment: I did, the shift keys acts as delete, but delete does not act as shift, I edited the question to include the output of those 2 grep commands.

Comment: @DanLaManna Then try to use `xmodmap -e "keycode 119 = Shift_L NoSymbol Shift_L"`. Is exactly the same thing. Maybe you have a problem depending on which keyboard layout are you using.