# How to remap keyboard permanently - Letters, not CapsLock or Num Lk

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, xmodmap

This is what i do

> xmodmap -e "keycode 135 = g"

but i lost it everytime i shutdown/restart my computer. I use ubuntu 14.04. Please someone can help me to make this change be permanent?

Thanks!

Comment: Answer from this question supposedly helped, according to the poster of the question: [Swapping right shift and delete key using xmodmap](http://askubuntu.com/questions/388415/swapping-right-shift-and-delete-key-using-xmodmap)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may potentially wish to put this into `/etc/rc.local`.  `rc.local` runs during the boot process, specifically at the end of the boot process.  It permits you to run certain commands at boot, but before you login.

This may be one option for making these changes.  However, note that this isn't a permanent solution later - if `/etc/rc.local` is changed or overwritten, you will have to put this back into `/etc/rc.local` of your own accord.

You will need superuser to edit this.  Either `sudo nano /etc/rc.local` for editing it in a command line, or `pkexec gedit /etc/rc.local` to edit it from the GUI program `gedit`.

---

**Caveats:**

You must make sure to keep `exit 0;` at the end of `rc.local`!  This is to ensure that it 'exits' with a 'no failure' code, otherwise you could have other tiny but annoying issues crop up during the boot process (such as errors in `dmesg` or otherwise indicating you had a problem during boot).

Comment: Sorry, but didnt work.

Comment: @MatheusMartinsJerônimo if it didn't work you can unaccept this answer and accept your own

Answer (score 0):

For those with the same problem, here's one solution:

https://askubuntu.com/a/388424/459031

Thanks!